# Simple "probing" program

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm not sure whether this exists or not, but I'm searching for a relatively simple program (Windows OS, preferably freeware) that probes folders (and their subfolders' subfolders - recursive scan) to determine whether a chosen file exists or not (e.g. Folder.jpeg - preferably case sensitive), and lists all the sub-directories where the said file is missing. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your 'case sensitive' requirement is not possible under Windows. If *folder.jpg* exists on the disk, asking Windows to look for *Folder.jpg* (or any other case variation) will always find a match.

Comment: I suspect you have an other requirement: you don't just want to find the folders missing the file, you want to copy the missing file to those folders. Am I correct? In that case you may not need this kind of software at all. Just copy the file to old subfolders (with overwrite).

Comment: Do you mean the exact same file, or just a matching file name? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Only a matching file name. I just want to find the folders where the file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Install [python](http://python.org) for windows, (free and a small download), then you can use os.walk in a simple .py script, if the following is in a script at a known location then it will search the current folder recursively when called from the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
LookingFor = 'Folder.jpeg' # case sensitive
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'): # Walk from the current directory down
    if '.svn' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('.svn')  # don't visit .svn directories as an example
    if LookingFor not in files: # this is case sensitive
        print root, 'is missing', LookingFor
```

*Note 1: the above is python 2, for python 3 change the last line to:*

```
        print(root, 'is missing', LookingFor)
```

*Note 2: Indentation is crucial and should be **all** spaces not tabs*